# SetInterval is not calling the function- javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

I need to use a timer on my page. I wrote in `document.ready` function the code below:

```
var timerForLoadingResult=  window.setInterval('checkSearchIsCompleted()',4000)
function checkSearchIsCompleted() {      
    alert('test');        
}
```

But it's not calling the function every 4 seconds. It's showing an error which says that the object is not found... What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper syntax is to pass the function name alone:

```
var timerForLoadingResult = window.setInterval(checkSearchIsCompleted,4000);
```

Comment: Though the reason it's not working is because a string can only be evaluated in global scope, while the OP mentioned that the above code is inside `document.ready`.